# Calling Soap Api in java with NTLM credentials and SSL certificate authentication

Tags: java, soap, ssl-certificate, ntlm-authentication

[image]Actually I am trying to call soap API in JAVA with `NTLM` authentication(username,password,domain) and SSL keystore certificate and keystore password (I tried in soapui it is working fine) same thing I need to achieve in java. Can any one guide me to achieve this in java. for NTLM authentication I referred `https://github.com/sujithtw/soapwithntlm` example.
Is there any better example for this in java.

Comment: Some code would do for us to understand what you have done and the errors you have gotten.

Comment: @AmosKosge  i did  above example but getting this error javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Comment: as per me ssl certification not added properly

Comment: This line needs to have the values you have used in your SoapUI request:
credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new NTCredentials("username","password","",""domain"));

Replace the values for Username and password and the domain with either variables or the correct parameters.

Comment: You may need to have the exceptions of these cases handled differently. The authentication and certificates registration into keystore.

Comment: those credentials (username ,password,domain) i added but same issue